# anaconda 4.3 pandas sum

Tags: pandas, numpy, anaconda

I recently installed anaconda 4.3 and when I try to do a sum using df["x"].sum() or np.sum(df["x"]) with a pandas dataframe read from excel I get a wrong answer. I also get a wrong answer while trying to use np.sum(x) or x.sum() on a random series, but when I np.sum(x) a random numpy array it gets the right answer.
This only happens since I installed the new version of anaconda, and with databases with more than 50000 rows aproximately.
My current setup is anaconda 4.3, pandas 0.19.2, numpy 1.11.3

Wrong pandas sum:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


a = np.random.randint(35000, high = 80000, size = 100000, dtype = np.int64) 
b = np.random.randint(1, high = 100, size = 100000)
c = np.sum(a)

d = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})

e = d["a"].sum()

f = np.sum(d["a"])

print(c,e,f)
```

```
5752269581 1457302285 1457302285
```

Wrong sum excel dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

w = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\asistentecrm\\Downloads\\Prueba2.xlsx")

x = w["Vlr. Neto"].sum()

y = w["Vlr. Neto"].values

z = np.sum(y)

print (x, z)
```

**-423117005** 3871850291

Sorry for my english and thanks for the help.

Comment: This behavior is generally observed on Windows wherein `numpy` uses 32-bit integers as default instead of a 64-bit one causing certain outcomes to overflow. If you specify `dtype=np.int64` while creating array `a`, then the results from both approaches would concur.

Comment: After specifying `dtype=np.int64` while creating the array `a` the `np.sum(a)` works fine, but now `e` gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: Sure, please check out the edited question.

Comment: This works fine however in *Anaconda* `4.2.9`, *Pandas* `0.19.2` & *NumPy* `0.12.0` (my configuration). I'd post this anomaly on their [GitHub repo's issue tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues) as the cause looks more likely due to your recent upgradation to `4.3` version.

Comment: That's what I will do, thanks for the help!